# Docker with gitlab access internal network

Tags: docker

I have a docker running gitlab on localhost perfectly on port 80. My problem is that I need other machines on the same internal network to access this my page that I created in Git's localhost.

Comment: Please provide more information, what is not working, what did you try, etc..

Comment: I created the docker, I put in my host the ip  "127.0.0.1 gitlab.exemple.com"  and it worked.I tried to use XAMPP but docker does not work because they are using the same port.

My goal is for other computers within my internal network to be able to access the site "gitlab.exemple.com" within the network interface, so I have to make my localhost be seen by other users